# Py file doesn't auto compile on Tornado Server

Tags: python, tornado

I did something as follows:

I'm working on a Tornado project and I'm new to Tornado.
When I want to mutate py source file, my modification is not take effect.It seems py file is not compiled.

Is there a way to make modified py file auto-compile at once under Tornado environment?

My python version is 3.3

Comment: Do you mean you want the change to take effect without restarting the Python/Tornado process?

Comment: did you restart your tornado server? Are you receiving any errors? Could you clear your old `*.pyc` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation is not the problem. The problem is that the Python process which is running the tornado server needs to be restarted.

You could use a program like [sniffer to restart the Python process every time it notices a change to the files](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sniffer). You just define a simple function that is run whenever a file is modified in a directory. Most people use it for automatically running tests but you could use it for restarting Python.

Comment: Thanks for your response.It's really useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Start the application in debug mode:

```
app = Application(..., debug=True)
```